# Calculating field with consecutive number based on another field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, unique-id

In QGIS I am working on a streets layer, on the attribute table I have these fields:

[image]

`"CVE_VIAL"` is an ID of the street and each street could be divided into several sections, each of these sections have an ID (`"ID_TRAMO"`) that  when concatenated with `"CVE_VIAL"` results in unique `"ID"`.

In this example, I've already calculated one by one `"ID_TRAMO"` with consecutive numbers, and what I'm trying to find right now is a way to do this automatically.

Comment: One question per Question, please (choose a platform, and tell us what you tried)

Comment: I feel like I've answered a question like this before... have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353618/using-a-dictionary-to-find-unique-values-from-one-field-populate-second-field-w/353620#353620 and see if it suits your needs, in your case CVE_VIAL replaces name and ID_TRAMO replaces ID_2 in my answer. If you don't have any python skills don't panic, the function can easily be modified to an advanced field calculation in ArcGIS *but* the function as written will have no respect for any values already assigned, again this isn't too difficult to fix if you need to keep existing

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

1. [Add autoincremental field](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#qgisaddautoincrementalfield), name it temp and group values by `"CVE_VIAL"`
2. Field Calculate a new string field named `"ID_TRAMO"` with the formula:

   ```
   lpad( to_string("temp"), 5, '0')
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
array_find(array_agg($id, group_by:=CVE_VIAL), $id) + 1
```